# Amazon Feed API - The file's header row is missing or invalid

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to submit a flat file (tab delimited) full of products. If I upload this file via the Upload Products & Inventory page is uploads correctly. However, if I try to use the API I get an error:

`The file's header row is missing or invalid. The header row is for Amazon use only and must not be modified or deleted. To correct this error, download the template again from seller Help and use that new copy, or insert the correct header row directly above the column headings in your existing file.`

The code I am using it the sample code, Feeds API Section Client Library - C#.

```
SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
request.Merchant = merchantId;
request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { marketplaceId });



request.FeedContent = File.Open(@"C:\Amazon_Upload_20141104_10.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
request.FeedContent.Position = 0;

request.FeedType = "_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_";

SubmitFeedSample.InvokeSubmitFeed(service, request);
```

Why would this file work through the web interface but not through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this by Google my problem was the incorrect feed type.

I had `_POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_`

When is should have been `_POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_`

For a list of feedTypes: [Click Here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html)